# ACI - Windows server 2019 - Can´t connect to internet

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I have an Azure Container Instance created from the base image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2019`. The container is running and i can connect to the web page via a public ip address.

The problem is that I cannot connect to the network from the container (for example, `Invoke-WebRequest http://google.com`)

If i run the following commands in container, everything is fine.

```
$nic = Get-NetAdapter
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $nic.IfIndex -ServerAddresses ('8.8.8.8')
```

Can you solve this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue for the image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2019` in ACI. All windows 2019 images may have this issue.
This issue happens because the DNS server is not set properly.
The commands you ran sets the DNS server to `8.8.8.8`. After that the container is able to resolve hostnames.

Current workaround is to run the same commands on the container startup or use the windows 2016 based images( tags 1607, ltsc2016 etc)